# waitpid for child process not succeeding

Tags: c, linux, process, pthreads, waitpid

I am starting a process using `execv` and letting it write to a file. I start a thread simultaneously that monitors the file so that it's size does not exceed a certain limit using `stat.st_size`. Now, when the limit is hit, I `waitpid` for the child process, but this throws an error and the process I start in the background becomes a zombie. When I do the stop using the same `waitpid` from the main thread, the process is killed without becoming a zombie. Any ideas?

Edit: The `errno` is 10 and `waitpid` returns -1. This is on a linux platform.

Comment: "but this throws an error ..." and that error would be... what? include error codes and all related messaging *verbatim* in you posted question. May as well also include the platform info.

Comment: waitpid returned -1 with errno set to 10. The errno seems to indicate that the child process does not exist. But that does not seem to be the case since I am able to see the process with a ps ax. The OS is linux.

Comment: And that would be in a *comment*.  That info belongs *in your posted question.* Regardless, perhaps the section on "Linux Notes" [in the documentation of `waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) may be related.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So if I use the option _WALL, I should be able to wait on child processes created by the main thread. I edited the question to include the error information.

Comment: A quick look at /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h show 10 is ECHILD (no child process). (You can convert errno to a string with strerror_r(3)).  Look at the waitpid(2) man page for more information.

Comment: Also please note: "The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. "  How are you starting the child process exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to debug without code, but `errno` 10 is `ECHILD`.

Per the man page, this is returned as follows:

> `ECHILD` (for `waitpid()` or `waitid()`) The process specified by `pid` (`waitpid()`) or `idtype` and `id` (`waitid()`) does not exist or is not a child of  the  calling process.  (This can happen for one's own child if the action for `SIGCHLD` is set to `SIG_IGN`.  See also the Linux Notes section about threads.)

In short, the `pid` you are specifying is not  a child of the process calling `waitpid()` (or is no longer, perhaps because it has terminated).

Note the parenthetical section:

- *"This can happen for one's own child if the action for `SIGCHLD` is set to `SIG_IGN`"* - if you've set up a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` to be `SIG_IGN`, the `wait` is effectively done automatically, and therefore `waitpid` won't work as the child will have already terminated (will not go through zombie state).
- *"See also the Linux Notes section about threads."* - In Linux, threads are essentially processes. Modern linux will allow one thread to wait for children of other threads (provided they are in the same thread group - broadly parent process). If you are using Linux prior to 2.4, this is not the case. See the documentation on `__WNOTHREAD` for details.

I'm guessing the thread thing is a red herring, and the problem is actually the signal handler, as this accords with your statement *'the process is killed without becoming a zombie.'*

Comment: I am not setting up a signal handler for SICHLD. So that should not be the issue. I am using a 2.6 kernel which should implicitly allow my thread to wait on the process created from the main thread. But that is not happening. I set the __WALL and __WCLONE options for waitpid to no avail. I will keep probing and get back to you. Thanks for the suggestions though.